# Chromedriver only supports characters in the BMP error while sending Emoji with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium Python to Tkinter's label() textbox

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, emoji

I am automating whatsapp messages and would like to send them out through a tkinter window. In this tkinter window I have created a message box with the help of .label() and I am able to connect to whatsapp web through selenium.

Currently, I am able to send out messages already, but without emojis. When I include emojis, I get this error "Chromedriver only supports characters in the BMP". How can I include emojis?

Comment: Which emoji did you try?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works (tested at 2023-12-25)

```
from selenium import webdriver

JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Python37\\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("https://google.com/")
elem = browser.find_element("xpath", "//textarea[@name='q']")

text = "  " + u'\u2764'

browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, elem, text)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this method, in my case `elem` is `browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[role='presentation'] div[role='textbox']")` but when I run `browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, elem, text)` nothing happens... could you help? Thanks. (the site I'm on is facebook, in particular I'm trying to enter emoji in the post editor)

Comment: sound wave, are you try send just text? With text it works ok?
And what version of webdriver you use?

Comment: This is not working anymore, What is new Event('change') ? Is there a possibility that it has been changed ?

Answer (score 12):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to send the **emoji** signal through `send_keys()` method.

[ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2269) is a known issue with *Chromium* team as *ChromeDriver* still doesn't support characters with a Unicode after `FFFF`. Hence it is impossible to send any character beyond `FFFF` via ChromeDriver. As a result any attempt to send **SMP** characters (e.g. *CJK*, *Emojis*, *Symbols*, etc) raises the error.

---

### Alternative

A potential alternative would be to use *GeckoDriver* / *Firefox*.

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  # Chineese Character
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("")
  # Emoji Character
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Emoji]

You can find a relevant discussion in [OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP while sending an emoji through C# Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439197/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chromedriver-only-supports-c)

---

### Outro

A few links:

- [Full Emoji List](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)
- [Unicode character inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%92%A9)

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you so much! Simply changing from chromedriver -> geckodriver and google chrome -> firefox allowed me to send emojis through.  Cheers!

Comment: ok so using a different driver and browser is an answer to chrome driver problem of supporting chars only in basic multilingual plane?

Answer (score 8):

Copy & Paste it !!!
It was so easy to round on this issue by copying the text to the clipboard and then pasting it into the element.
[image: pasting a text that contains emojis]

```
import pyperclip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
title = driver.title
assert title == "Google"

driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

search_box = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="q")

pyperclip.copy("Hi  This is a test message ! ")
act = ActionChains(driver)
act.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("v").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who wants to send emojis on Chrome

**Solution**

```
    async sendKeysWithEmojis(element, text) {
        const script = `var elm = arguments[0],
        txt = arguments[1];elm.value += txt;
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup', {bubbles: true}));`;
        await this.driver.executeScript(script, element, text);
    }
```

**Call it like so**

```
const element = await this.driver.findElement(selector);
await sendKeysWithEmojis(element, ' This one shall pass ');
```

**What is happening here?**
We are emulating native key presses using events

Notice that the `{bubbles: true}` is optional (Was needed in my case due to a complex wrapped input)

Comment: do you know if it is possible to use this method in python too? I'm trying to adapt your code but have some problems

Comment: I have no idea but I don't see a reason why not as this code is mostly javascript and one command in python "executeScript"

Comment: thanks for fast reply, for example if I run the first code my console prompt this error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and it says the error is at `sendKeysWithEmojis`

Comment: Can you share the code on some platform and paste the link here?

Comment: The code I run is the one you wrote here in the answer: `async sendKeysWithEmojis(element, text) {...}`, when I run it in python it gives me that error

Comment: remove the `async` and `await` part - those are js syntax

Comment: Haha. yeah `const` is also not part of python language - also the ` (Tag) sign should probably be replaced with """ at the beginning and at the end of the string

Comment: thanks, now it says error at `script`  ahaha i think there is no way don't worry its ok I don't want to bother you

Comment: I suggest you refer to some python course to better know the language. Then you can see an example here of running javascript inside python (Which is what needed to run the above code) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345

Answer (score 3):

there was an open bug on chrome driver website, the bug as been fixed this month (14.11.21)

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2269

this is the bug report.

**how to use new chrome driver:**

first go to:
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/942085/

download the chrome driver from there.(the first mark as showen in image).

then you will need to install the new chrome v98 using the mini_installer.exe

**(pay attantion its all expermintal)**,

without this you could not use the new driver due to version compitity.

next i needed to delete the current chrome version to make this work good.
[image]

your are all welcome to ask me question about it, i mange to make it work with the versions i add here on whatsapp using selenium chrome driver.

**EDIT:**
[image]
chrome versions 98 stable will come out in 30 days, so you could try to install the beta version and not the chromium version and see if it's working.

you don't have to delete the old chrome version, I know this thread is about python but in java (i guess python support it too) you could do this:

```
options.setBinary(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Local\\Chromium\\Application\\chrome.exe");
```

and it will set the path to the chromium version.

Comment: I'm now using Chrome+Chromedriver v.111 and still getting this error. Does that match your experience?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
js_code = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
"""

your_text = 'this my text '
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="input"]')
driver.execute_script(js_code, element, your_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed this using VBA and ChromeDriver in Excel SeleniumBasic:

```
objIE.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", Array(objIE.FindElementById("sqlvalue1"), Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Value)
```

This avoids using `SendKeys` which is what errors when it is run with this error message.