# Typing string directly following non-us language keyboard in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, unicode, encoding, sendkeys

When I use `send_keys(string)` to web browser, it just types directly following my non-US keyboard.

For example, there was a string like `Smart Factory 보고서` and I wanted to send the string to the web using `send_keys()`

Example code is below,

```
string_value = "Smart Factory 보고서"
elem.send_keys(string_value)
```

The problem is that it returns `Smart Factory qhrhtj` because  typing of `보고서` is same as typing of `qhrhtj`

My explanation is bad.. but it really makes me crazy.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the specific type of these characters **Smart Factory 보고서**. However it seems some of them are [special characters with a unicode after FFFF](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2269) and using *ChromeDriver* /*Chrome* if you try to send those characters you can face an error as:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
```

> You can find a detailed discussing in [Chromedriver only supports characters in the BMP error while sending Emoji with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium Python to Tkinter's label() textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138825/chromedriver-only-supports-characters-in-the-bmp-error-while-sending-emoji-with/59139690#59139690)

---

However using [geckodriver](/questions/tagged/geckodriver) / [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) combo and inducing *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` you can easily send the special characters following the solution:

```
string_value = "Smart Factory 보고서"
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_locator"))).send_keys(string_value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't post that I use IEdriver not Chrome or firefox.
Also, the strange characters are actually Korean. 
I think this occurs when NON-US language keyboard is used

Comment: @JinhwanLee With _IEdriver_ it would work like _GeckoDriver_

Comment: However,, the answer is not I want..  I can send keys to element but wrong strings

Comment: @JinhwanLee Can you update the question with the relevant HTML?

Comment: I cant show all HTML code because it is confidential....I figure out the encoding of html is UTF-8


`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10;charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10;charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10;charset=UTF-8">`