# How to adapt a Selenium Javascript "sendKeysWithEmojis" code to Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I just found a possible solution to a sendKeysWithEmojis issue I am having and it is written for Selenium in Javascript and I would like to translate it to python so I can test in in my infrastructure and be able to . The solution is the following:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478726/12474157

```
 async sendKeysWithEmojis(element, text) {
        const script = `var elm = arguments[0],
        txt = arguments[1];elm.value += txt;
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup', {bubbles: true}));`;
        await this.driver.executeScript(script, element, text);
    }
```

To execute:

```
const element = await this.driver.findElement(selector);
await sendKeysWithEmojis(element, ' This one shall pass ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I don't understand what is the problem.

I took first answer from your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60478726/12474157) and it works for me with `Chrome` and with text `' This one shall pass '` on page Google.com

```
from selenium import webdriver

JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://google.com/")
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('q')

text = ' This one shall pass '

browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, elem, text)
```

But if you really need version from JavaScript then you have to only change text in `JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT`

```
from selenium import webdriver

JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
        var elm = arguments[0],
        txt = arguments[1];elm.value += txt;
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup', {bubbles: true}));
"""

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://google.com/")
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('q')

text = ' This one shall pass '

browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, elem, text)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or maybe your problem is to put it in function

```
from selenium import webdriver

def sendKeysWithEmojis(element, text):
    JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
            var elm = arguments[0],
            txt = arguments[1];elm.value += txt;
            elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown', {bubbles: true}));
            elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {bubbles: true}));
            elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
            elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup', {bubbles: true}));
    """

    browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, elem, text)

# --- main ---

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://google.com/")

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('q')

text = ' This one shall pass '

sendKeysWithEmojis(elem, text)
```

---

OR maybe problem is only on `Windows` - I tested on `Linux`.

OR maybe problem is `Chrome/ChromeDriver` - I tested on `Chorme/ChromeDriver 95.0.4638.69`